# Is it against the HTML spec to position child elements of a div outside of the div?

Tags: html

[image]

**The image above provides a visual for the following code**

- The blue rectangle is the parent div.
- The red square is the child image.

> ```
>  <!-- a centered fixed-width parent div -->
>  <div style="position: relative; width: 400px; height: 200px; margin: 0px auto;">
>     <img src="46px_square.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: -46px; left: -46px;" />
>  </div>
> ```

As you can see, from a spatial perspective, the child element is outside of the parent, despite being a child element in the DOM.

Is this fair-use, according to the HTML overlords?

Comment: Yes this is fair use and can be achieved using absolute/relative positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people uses `fixed` and `absolute` positions for positioning some elements, this is what positioning is for, generally these elements are out of the document flow, so it is absolutely fine that the `child` element is outside of the `parent` element, it makes no difference to the `validation` unless and until you use some invalid child element in your parent container.

For Example:

```
<p>
  <p>This won't pass your validation, no matter what positions you use for these element</p>
</p>
```

And always use `position: relative;` to your parent element so that the child doesn't flow out in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly valid but you will be using position:absolute.relative to make them sit at proper places. This creates a caveat for pages when you want to load this on Mobile devices.